# How can i define a \mathcal{h} character, without switching the font set for all other characters

Tags: mathcal

For a physics text i need a lower case mathcal h (for energy density), as a companion to upper case mathcal H (for energy). I would prefer a solution, that does not require to switch to complete font set from my default.

Comment: What's the current default font for `\mathcal{H}`?